# Random array element creation into Dom only once JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, random

I've got a problem to insert a random array element into the DOM. I want it to only do it once for each array element but the code keeps fetching the element infinitely.

I'm doing a card game and want the code to understand that I'm picking a card from the deck, so it should delete it from the array. but it keeps on going and repeat the same cards over and over when I click the button. The button should draw randomly a card only once.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

    <title>TEST</title>

    <style>
    .testDivExe{
        border: 0.1em dashed black;
        
        width: 100%;

        background-color: rgb(192,192,192,0.6);
    }
    
    body{
        border: 0.1em dotted black;
        
        font-family: impact;
        font-size: 2em;
        background-color: rgb(192,192,192,0.4);
    }
    </style>
    </head>


    <header>
        <h1>ZONE</h1>
    </header>


    <body>
        <div class="testDivExe" id="testDivExeId">
            <button id="testClickId">click</button>
        <div>

    <footer>
    </footer>

    <script>
    //TEST1
    document.getElementById("testClickId").onclick = function testFunc1(){
        // RAND AND ARR
        var array1 = ["Hello", "There", "Some", "Things", "Never", "Change",];
    
    
        
        var deal = function(){
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length);
            var card = array1[index];
            array1.splice(index, 1);
            return card;        
        };

        // PER&CRE
        var object = document.createElement('p');
        object.innerHTML = deal(array1);

        //REND
        document.getElementById("testDivExeId").appendChild(object);
        
        return false;
    };

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to define the array outside of the click handler. Right now each click uses a new array, hence it is repeating words.

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS. ALL CAPS comes across as shouting.

Comment: Thank you guys, your help solved the problem and allowed me to better understand how the code works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array1` is created every time you click the button. You must store `array1` in such a way that it retains its current value. You can declare `array1` in the global scope or store the array in the browser memory. You should actually remove the card from the array (I recommend you use `filter` instead of `splice`). Finally make sure to create a new `<p>` only when at least one card exist.

```js
<script>
    //TEST1

    // RAND AND ARR
    var array1 = ["Hello", "There", "Some", "Things", "Never", "Change",];

    document.getElementById("testClickId").onclick = function testFunc1() {
        if (array1.length === 0) // Check if exists any card.
            return;
        var deal = function () {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length);
            var card = array1[index];
            array1 = array1.filter(c => c !== card); // Remove the card
            return card;
        };

        // PER&CRE
        var object = document.createElement('p');
        object.innerHTML = deal(array1);

        //REND
        document.getElementById("testDivExeId").appendChild(object);

        return false;
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I was struggling with this one for about 2 days until I decided to post this... Cheers.